Special Characters in Auto Slug Field
I'm trying to find the solution to a problem I encounter when using prepopulated_fields.
I use this function to create a slug based on an entered title. However, if I insert special characters (+, -, etc.) in the title the slug cannot pick them up.
Do you have any idea how to make these special characters read, so that the slug is consistent with the title?
Example:
Title | Samsung Galaxy S24+
Slug (should become) | samsung-galaxy-s24+
or something similar
This is my current code:
models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    titolo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    descrizione = RichTextUploadingField('Text', config_name='default', blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

admin.py
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('titolo',)}


A slug is exactly meant not to encode +, since + means space, and therefore if you need +, it would be encoded as %2b, so a slug tries to prevent percentage encoding.

Slug is a newspaper term and is a short label for something, containing only letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens. It does not contain any other special characters. As long as you're using the SlugField, note that it must follow this convention. If you want special characters included, you can use CharField in your URLs.

Ok, but if I use CharField is there a way to also use prepopulated_fields so that it also copies the special characters?

You can do something like this in your models: title = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255) then in your urls.py: path('your_route/<str:title>', your_view, name=your_name)

slugfield use slugfy, and slugfy not use +.
if you use +, you could use charfield and custom create slug.
